# Installation issue in laravel bundle with commands

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel. I have never used artisan commands. Now I'm trying to install a bundle, but it says to run this commands: `php artisan bundle:install charisma` and `php artisan bundle:publish. I don't know how to run these commands and WHERE to run these commands for installation. Can anyone please tell me step by step how and where these commands work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run those commands at the terminal.

Let's suppose you have Laravel installed on `documents/projects/test`.

```
cd documents/projects/test
php artisan bundle:install charisma
```

Comment: thanks. I will try this. Can you please give a url of any tutorial to complete guide. I couldn't find one.

Comment: The [commands documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/artisan/commands) is the only one that I know of, even tho it assumes that users know where to run them.

Comment: Thanks @ViníciusFragosoPinheiro. I tried and successfully installed it.